# How to get current location at the instant UIImagePickerController captures an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, swift, geolocation

I have researched on how to get location data from images returned from `UIImagePickerController` camera. However, I think that the easiest way is to get the current location from `CLLocationManager` at the instant `UIImagePickerController` captures an image.

Is there a way of doing this? Is there a way of listening for the "capturePhoto" event, for example?

Just to clarify, the users using my app will likely be moving pretty fast.

Comment: You could keep track of the device's location starting sometime before actually taking the picture then save the current location at time of image capture.

Comment: @LyndseyScott thanks, but the problem is that the user using my app will likely be moving pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd recommend so you don't track the user's location any more than you have to and so you get the user's location closest to the time the image was actually snapped.

Instantiate the `CLLocationManager` class variable in your `viewDidLoad`, ex:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
```

And make sure it's authorized:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

(Also include the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" key in the .plist)

Then you could wait until the `UIImagePickerController` is actually presented before (1) initializing the dictionary to hold the locations and (2) starting to update the location, ex:

```
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
self.locationDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

At that point, you can start storing the user's updated locations in an `NSMutableDictionary` `self.locationDictionary` class instance variable when `CLLocation` values are returned from the `didUpdateToLocation` delegate method, ex:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // Format the current date time to match the format of
    // the photo's metadata timestamp string
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY:MM:dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // Add the location as a value in the location NSMutableDictionary
    // while using the formatted current datetime as its key
    [self.locationDictionary setValue:newLocation forKey:stringFromDate];
}
```

And then once the image is selected, find its timestamp in the metadata and find the value in the location dictionary with a timestamp key closest to the image timestamp, ex:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // When a photo is selected save it as a UIImage
    self.selectedPhoto = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    // Get the timestamp from the metadata and store it as an NSString
    self.selectedPhotoDateTime = [[[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] objectForKey:@"{Exif}"] objectForKey:@"DateTimeOriginal"];

    // If the CLLocationManager is in fact authorized
    // and locations have been found...
    if (self.locationDictionary.allKeys.count > 0) {

        // Sort the location dictionary timestamps in ascending order
        NSArray *sortedKeys = [[self.locationDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

        // As a default, set the selected photo's CLLocation class
        // variable to contain the first value in the sorted dictionary
        self.selectedPhotoLocation = [self.locationDictionary objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:0]];

        // Then go through the location dictionary and set the
        // photo location to whatever value in the dictionary
        // has a key containing a time most closely before
        // the image timestamp. Note that the keys can be compared
        // as strings since they're formatted in descending order --
        // year to month to day to hour to minute to second.
        for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {

            // If the photo's metadata timestamp is less than or equal to
            // the current key, set the selected photo's location class
            // variable to contain the CLLocation value associated with the key
            if ([self.selectedPhotoDateTime compare:key] != NSOrderedAscending) {
                self.selectedPhotoLocation = [self.locationDictionary objectForKey:key];
            }

            // Else if the time in the location dictionary is past
            // the photo's timestamp, break from the loop
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the code. But the problem is that this imagepickercontroller delegate method is only called when the user taps the white button **and then after** the user taps the User Photo button, and there will likely be a time difference between two button taps. The users using the app will likely be moving pretty fast.

Comment: @VictorPrograss Even if the user's moving fast, this will still work. `didUpdateToLocation:` continuously receives location updates once you call `startUpdatingLocation`. And the code I wrote records the user's location at the exact time the image is taken.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. But how do you get the time when the image is taken?

Comment: @VictorPrograss You could add `NSDate *dateTime = [NSDate date];` in that `if(confirm)` block to get the time at image capture.

Comment: Yeah, but there will be time gap between when the user taps the shutter button, and when he/she actually taps the use photo button. Is there a way to get the time from UIImagePickerControllerMetadata?

Comment: @VictorPrograss FYI I've (1) updated my answer to use `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` instead of the deprecated `didFinishPickingImage:` method, I've also (2) updated my answer to show you how to access the time stamp in the metadata, and I've (3) updated the answer to actually get the location at/nearest to the time of the shutter click.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.h file` you need to add the following to your code:

```
@interface TakePhotoViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

In your `.m file` you need the following.

```
@interface TakePhotoViewController (){
    //location stuff
    CLLocationManager * manager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark * placemark;

}
```

The above code set's up relevant references to find your location.

Next add this to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
```

This initialises the Location Manager and Geocoder.

Then in your code that either initiates taking a picture or returns the picture to a view use this:

```
manager.delegate = self;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

To stop the continuous updating of the location add this to your imagePickerReturn method:

```
[manager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

**As soon as you stop updating the location you will be saving the very last location that was updated. The location updates once every .5 - 1 second, so even if you are moving or have the camera open for a long time it will only store the location of whatever image you pick.** To save the date (which includes time down to milliseconds) use:

```
NSDate * yourCoreDataDateName = [NSDate date];
```

For good coding practice to handle any errors you will need this:

```
//handles the error if location unavailable
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to get location... :-(");

}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation * currentLocation = newLocation;

    self.locationTF.text = @"Finding Location...";

    if (currentLocation != nil){


        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0){

            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            //the code below translates the coordinates into readable text of the location
            self.locationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ , %@, %@, %@ %@", placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.locality, placemark.administrativeArea, placemark.country, placemark.postalCode];

        }

        else{
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
            self.locationLabel.text = @"Failed to find location";
        }
    }];
    }

}
```

I must warn you that iOS8 will throw *NO* error when it can't find a location because it needs you as the programmer to add an alert view to authorise getting locations. See this tutorial on how to overcome this issue:

http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

I got this tutorial from the most popular asked question about the new error.

Comment: thanks, but i did not see a way of how to actually implement the custom image picker controller to get the current location at the instant of photo capture.

Comment: You use [manager startUdatingLocation]; to the location. It would be triggered by switching to camera. Then when you return with your chosen image it would stop updating, saving the last location. The location continuously updates until you tell it to stop.

Comment: @VictorPrograss - Ensure that you use the tutorial I have attached in the answer (it's the easiest to follow and best explained I found) to avoid the iOS 8 error as many people have been forced to update existing apps to cater for the changes. It does not present any error to user what so ever, it will simply not perform any location service.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate way to do this would be through the exif metadata. Have a look at [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/) post by Ole Begemann on how to do this.

**UPDATE**

It seems like Apple doesn't include the location to the metadata to images taken with the Camera from the UIImagePicker.

Another option to get the location in which the image was taken would be to use a custom overlay view for the UIImagePicker and get the location when the [takePicture](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) method is called. This would probably achieve the best result.

Comment: Yeah but does it work with newly captured photos? I don't think UIImagePickerController give us the URL for newly captured photos.

Comment: The NSDictionary in - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info contains the EXIF metadata for the image even if it's being captured with the camera BUT it looks like Apple is not adding the location to the metadata unlike images taken with the Camera app. That seems strange.