# how to show latitude and longitude when i capture a image in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Whenever i take a photo i just want latitude and longitude of the image and i don't want to save the image, i just want the longitude and latitude of the image.

How to get the longitude and latitude of the image whenever i capture a image, here i am using ui image picker controller for camera.

```
- (IBAction)btnCameraAction:(id)sender
{
UIImagePickerController *imagePickController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickController.delegate=self;
imagePickController.allowsEditing=TRUE;
[self presentViewController:imagePickController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any code help is well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when camera delegate didfinishpickingimage is called then get image and access its property size which will give you height and width of image

Answer (score 0):

You should really use the `ALAssetsLibrary`. It's much more comfortable:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    self.imgInf = info;

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myass)
    {
        CLLocation *location = [myass valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
        UIImage *image = [self.imgInf objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *err)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [al assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
}

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

You can get different information about the image via other flags:

`ALAssetPropertyType
ALAssetPropertyLocation
ALAssetPropertyDuration
ALAssetPropertyOrientation
ALAssetPropertyDate
ALAssetPropertyRepresentations
ALAssetPropertyURLs`

EDIT:
I changed the sourceType so it will meet your requirements.

Comment: here url when i am posting in log it is coming null.

Comment: i don't want  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary i just want a instantly update the latitude and longitude and i will not store that image to my gallery.

Comment: I missunderstood your question. You can use the delegate of UIImagePickerController - concrete the method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo I described above. You'll need the ALAssetsLibrary to access NSDictionary which will contain the data you are looking for.

Comment: i am getting nil for location, what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Image don't have any latitude and longitude.

you can do in bellow way.

either by your app when you capture the image, you can check and save the current location by

```
//To get user location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    getCurrentLatitude = coordinate.latitude;
    getCurrentLongitude = coordinate.longitude;
```

and save along with image with any local resource and latter on you can use same when ever you have need.

also you can extract address by CLGeoCoder

or you can have a look at this SO question: [Hot to get current location at the instant UIImagePickerController captures an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391564/how-to-get-current-location-at-the-instant-uiimagepickercontroller-captures-an-i)

Comment: What do you mean images don't have latitude and longitude? The EXIF data clearly have it. P.S. Still, I agree, that your approach is actually usable.